# picture box crossed out C#

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d, picturebox, gdi

I have a project in which I draw several rectangles using GDI. I do it using `i++ from i=0 to i<=10`. I use `e.Graphics.FillRectangles`. I refresh the drawn rectangles every 1/10s by calling `Graphics.Invalidate()`
My problem is that my picture box gets crossed out when drawing more the 4 rectangles. I guess it's because the picture box is out of memory.
What can I do against it?

Thx in advance :D

Comment: Without the code its going to be impossible to tell, what do you mean by "crossed out"?

Comment: Please show (part of) your code. I think the issue is not in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This red cross appears when an **uncaught exception is thrown during the paint** of the control. The most common cause of this is, that one has attached a custom handler to the `Paint` event of the contol and has a bug in the attached code, that leads to the exception getting thrown.

Surround your custom paint logic with a `try...catch` block and log the exception to a location of your liking (Debug.WriteLine(), file, etc.) to investigate.

A by product of this will be: The *red cross will immediatly vanish*, because the exception is no longer passed down to the drawing routine of the control.